# Fetch works by categoryId

Tags: javascript, html, api, dynamic

Hello i am learning JS actually i try to fetch some data from an API, i have fetch all the work from api/works and display them in a div but now i need to create 3 button who represent the 3 category who regroup all works, i created dynamically the buttons but now i need to put a function on these button to display the api/works from the category id give (example button 1 represent category id 1 and when i click, all api/works from category id 1 are displayed, same for 2nd et 3rd button) there is the json format for data

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Abajour Tahina",
    "imageUrl": "http://localhost:5678/images/abajour-tahina1651286843956.png",
    "categoryId": 1,
    "userId": 1,
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Objets"
    }
  }
```

i don't know how said fetch all works but with categoryId 1, hide all and display these categoryId of works

if someone know how to do this or documentation to doing this

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Clear the container element
    document.getElementById("works").innerHTML = "";
    // Make GET request to API endpoint for all works with categoryId 1
    fetch("http://localhost:5678/api/works?categoryId=1")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Loop through the list of works
        data.forEach(function(work) {
            // Create a new HTML element for each work
            var workElement = document.createElement("div");
            workElement.innerHTML = "Work ID: " + work.id + "<br>" + "Title: " + work.title + "<br>" + "Content: " + work.content;
            // Append the new HTML element to the page
            document.getElementById("works").appendChild(workElement);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

i tried this but he give me all /works the url http://localhost:5678/api/works?categoryId=1 not working for me i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put console.log on the function that handle the click on button to see if the function is actualy triggerd.

i think because your buttons are dynamically added javascript can't recognize them.

Comment: this should be a comment. not an answer